# How do you clear everything in the Docker build cache except for a particular run cache?

Tags: docker

Since the Docker build cache is taking up a lot of my disk space, I want to clear it using `docker builder prune`. However, there is a particular build cache that I do **not** want to be cleared, because it takes a very long time to regenerate from scratch. The relevant line in my Dockerfile that defines the build cache is this:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/app/zopflipng-cache \
    python3 /app/compress_and_cache_png_images.py \
        dist \
        --cache-dir /app/zopflipng-cache
```

See also https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#use-the-dedicated-run-cache.

How can I clear everything in the build cache except for the `/app/zopflipng-cache` cache?

I see that there is a `--filter` option that is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_prune/#description), but it doesn't seem to offer a way to do what I want.